# NavigateUri as a DynamicResource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using resource dictionaries for multilangual support and link my labels as a DynamicResource. However, is there an easy way to use a hyperlink's NavigateUri as a DynamicResource as well? I cannot find any Uri type's in mscorlib. The Uri where the hyperlink control should link to is language dependant and I would love to keep it easy and have the hyperlink in my dictionaries.

In the dictionary:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<system:String x:Key="ww-url-label">Password forgotten?</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="ww-url">https://somelink</system:String>
```

In the window xaml:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="{DynamicResource ww-url}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource ww-url-label}" />
</Hyperlink>
```

Obviously the NavigateUri doesn't work. I could of course add the link programmatically, but I would prefer to keep it in the ResourceDictionary... Is there an easy trick to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously the NavigateUri doesn't work

It's not *obviously*. If you get error - always add it to the question.

Your mistake is that you are trying to use `string` to specify `Uri`, so you get

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Uri'.

Make this change to define `ww-url` and you should be fine:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System" ...>
    <sys:Uri x:Key="ww-url">https://somelink</sys:Uri>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: I already tried that, since I thought it was obvious I could not link a string to an Uri type. However Uri was not available in mscorlib. Thank you so much for your answer, I have added the System assembly and now sys:Uri is working! Thanks!